# External web service for sending background emails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid, rails-activejob

I've used [this instructions](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) and sent "Welcome" mail to my signed up user. But this makes the user wait for 5-8 seconds because the server is trying to complete this mail thing.

I don't want the user to wait until the mail is sent but immediately see the "Mail has sent" message. So this brings me background jobs in Rails.
There are many options like delayed_job, Resque etc for background jobs in Rails. But to use these kind of solutions, as I understand:

1- Create a background job
2- Run this job

Let's say I used one of the background job solutions, so then I need something else to run also this job, like cron job...

I think just for sending sign-up and password reminder emails, another easier solution should be possible. I mean like another external service that 1- I'll create a template for each kind of mail I'll send, 2- I'll pass some arguments like receiver_email, template_id, receiver_username, password_link etc... With that way, I won't need any background job, and the user will not wait.

I came across some other gem called "sucher_punch" but as I understand from the people's messages and posted problems, with using heroku, this gem can fail for some reasons of heroku dynos and the mail may not be sent, and you don't know it.

Anyway, what is the general way that rails developers handle this email issue? Maybe I can also use sendgrid like the way I explained above, can I ?

Comment: Hi Enis. If you feel the answer helped you accomplish what you intended, please consider accepting it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending emails in the background is such a common use case, Rails 4.2 introduced a `#deliver_later` method in `ActionMailer` to provide seamless `ActiveJob` integration.

You don't need to set up a cron job to check if there are any jobs in the background queue. Sidekiq, Resque or DelayedJob will take care of that for you.

It seems Sendgrid does allow [creating templates](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/transactional-email-templates/) and sending variable content to fill them up, but that feature doesn't undermine the benefits of making that call asynchronously. In fact, deferring it to the background also has the added benefit of not disrupting user experience if the external resource(Sendgrid) is unavailable.

You should try installing one of the background processing solutions you mentioned(I recommend [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)) and take advantage of the [ActionMailer + ActiveJob integration](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html).